# know if Windows user is active

Tags: .net, windows

In windows I can log in and switch of user without logging out. Like that I can have multiple users logged in but only one working. How can I know which of the users is currently working.

Comment: Is this a normal application, or are you running as a service?

Comment: You can only have one user active in the console session, but several can be working at the same time through Terminal Services for instance. Should these sessions be ignored?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, these sessons are ignored. Normally I will only have people working in the same phisical PC nothing remote

Comment: @egrunin it is a windows forms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the .NET framework does not expose to managed code the API required to achieve this. You will have to p/invoke quite a few WINAPI functions and define at least one structure and some enums on the .NET side.

If you're willing to follow that path, you can:

- Call [WTSEnumerateSessions()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx), passing `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` in the `hServer` argument,
- Iterate over the returned [WTS_SESSION_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383864.aspx) structures and locate the one whose `State` member has the `WTSActive` and `WTSConnected` bits set (there should only be one in your case),
- Pass the `SessionId` member of that structure to [WTSQuerySessionInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx), specifying `WTSUserName` in the `WTSInfoClass` argument,
- Read the user name from the returned buffer,
- Use [WTSFreeMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383834.aspx) to free the buffer and the array of `WTS_SESSION_INFO` structures.

As you can see, this isn't really trivial. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found a very good example of microsoft in c# ([Detect the Windows session state](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSDetectWindowsSessionState-f27d0321) ).

They register to the system event "SessionSwitch"

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e){
...
}
```

it needs a dependency in Win32

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

I tried and it work very good and relatively easy.